# How to change each word in a string to upper case?

Tags: java, string, apache-stringutils

I am trying to find a why in Spring, Java to upper case each word in a string?

Can StringUtils do it?

Comment: Do you mean to upper-case the *first letter* of each word?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `toUpperCase()` method in `String`.

```
String x = "lowercasestring";
x = x.toUpperCase();
System.out.println(x);
```

The output will be `LOWERCASESTRING`

**EDIT :**

You can use the `WordUtils` class of the Apache Commons-lang. The capitalize method will convert the first letter of a space separated words. The following code demonstrates it:

```
String x = "a lower case string";
x = WordUtils.capitalize(x);
System.out.println(x);
```

The output will be `A Lower Case String`. You can also refer the docs for the `WordUtils` class [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html#capitalize%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: no this will do everything.. I only want the first letter of each word